# Maximize sum of subset of arrays under given cost

Tags: arrays, algorithm, cost-based-optimizer

I have an array of n Objects with an int 'value' and another int 'cost'. I want to get the subset of size k (k < n) of that array that maximizes the sum of the values. For instance...

**Value - Cost**

32 - 24

25 - 17

39 - 40

10 - 10

47 - 44

0 - 10

18 - 10

I need to choose, say, 5 of those that will maximize value while staying below a certain total cost (say, 100). **I don't get bonus points for having the lowest cost**, only for having the highest value. I'm not looking to get the most bang for my buck, I'm looking to get the most bang, while staying below a given buck.

Is there just a name for the algorithm I'm looking for? I don't want to have to brute force it.

Comment: I believe that would be an instance of the 0-1 [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Definition). Cost here would be equivalent to weight in the classic formulation.

Comment: Something like [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445874/knapsack-0-1-with-fixed-quanitity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445874/knapsack-0-1-with-fixed-quanitity)

Comment: Wow that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks! Now I just need to turn that into C#. Thanks for all your help!